# Find the approximate limit of $f=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\chi_{[1/k, 1/k+2^{-k}]}$ at zero

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

I need to find the approximate limit of $f=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\chi_{[1/k, 1/k+2^{-k}]}$ at zero.

> **Definition**: $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ has approximate limit $\lambda$ at $x$ if $$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{m_n(B(x, r)\cap\{|f-\lambda|>\epsilon\})}{m_n(B(x, r))}=0.$$

Clearly only options are $0$ or $1$. But the measure of the set close to zero where $f$ is one tends to zero. So I think the approximate limit should be $0$. Then I should estimate  $$m_n(B(0, r)\cap \{|f|>\epsilon\})=m_n(B(0, r)\cap \{f=1\}).$$
The set where $f=1$ is the union $$\{f=1\}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{k}, \frac{1}{k}+2^{-k}].$$ Therefore I should estimate the measure of $$\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}[0, r]\cap[\frac{1}{k}, \frac{1}{k}+2^{-k}].$$ But I don't know how to proceed. Any help is welcome.

Comment: The sum of the lengthes of the intervals on $k\geqslant n$ is at most $2/2^n$ hence, the intersection in your post has measure at most of the order $1/2^n$ if $r$ is of order $1/n$, qed.

Comment: @Did thank you very much, I didn't see that it was that easy